# Is clip-on tuner suitable for stage in orchestra?

Tags: violin, classical-music, string-instruments, orchestra, tuner

I googled and saw videos in `youtube` about tuning in `classical orchestra` during their live performance. I was wonder if somebody tell me that using `clip-on tuner` for instruments (like `violin`) in `classical orchestra` in their performance on stage in front of many people is usual and good? or this isn't usual?

Comment: I've never seen professionals use these. I've seen a few student orchestras use them. As Carl answered, the most precise tuning would not be possible with a digital tuner since the orchestra has to be in tune with itself more than it has to be tuned to an arbitrary standard. Since clip ons are easy to use, they can streamline the process of getting in the right ballpark for younger players or those with less developed tuning ability.

Comment: A clip-on tuner can help sometimes, but not very often. In the orchestra we need to listen to each other and intonate (tune) together. With experience this gets better, professional players have that experience. Amateurs, maybe, as it is can be a distraction. Personally, beeing an amateur, I tend to use a clip-on when playing contrabassoon. It is a weird instrument, in that it can be very difficult to actually hear the intonation when playing.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's useless.  You need to tune to the **orchestra**, not to a predefined frequency.

Comment: It seems you don't understand my question, We all have tune in the orchestra at first of the live performance, but during live performance(in the middle) we want to tune again, If everybody has clip-on tuner, is this bad?

Comment: A professional musician doesn't need a tuner - just his/her ears.

Comment: The point carl is making is that the oboe (generally) that the orchestra tunes to may or may not be exactly at A=440Hz - so-called 'concert pitch - although that varies round the world. Whatever note the oboe produces is the pitch for that concert. Even if you used a really expensive tuner, unless you re-set it to accept that oboe's pitch, it wouldn't be correct. Apart - I'd think an orchestra with clip on tuners was pretty naff.

Comment: N.B. *Naff* means "lacking taste or style", according to one online dictionary. I had to look it up so I figured I'd assist any other Americans here.

Comment: @ToddWilcox  Awwwww, you took all the fun of people having to go learn about someother country's slang  :-)

Comment: Unfortunately lazy people like me often try to work from context clues instead of actual learning, so I used to think *naff* was more like "wicked fresh" but now I see it's really closer to "bogus".